# Comparing strings in a JDO query fails when value contains a "Comma"

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am attempting to check for an existing string using a JDO query, in my attempt to prevent the insertion of a duplicate string.

My query to check for an existing string works fine, unless the two strings I am comparing have a comma in the value. If the commas exists, the comparison bombs using "==".

For example, if I query to see if "Architecture" exists, I get the right result (Horrray!).
If I attempt to see if "Architecture, Engineering, and Drafting" exists, and it does, the query comes back and says an identical value does not exist (Boo!).

The code I'm using is as follows:

**Called from the RPC**

```
public void addCommas()
{
    final Industry e = new Industry();
    e.setIndustryName("Architecture, Engineering, and Drafting");
    persist(e);
}

public void addNoCommas()
{
    final Industry e = new Industry();
    e.setIndustryName("Architecture");
    persist(e);
}
```

**Persist Operation**

```
private void persist(Industry industry)
{
    if (industryNameExists(industry.getIndustryName()))
    {
        return;
    }
    final PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.currentTransaction().begin();
    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(industry);
        pm.flush();
        pm.currentTransaction().commit();
    } catch (final Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } finally
    {
        if (pm.currentTransaction().isActive())
        {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
        }
    pm.close();
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
public static boolean industryNameExists(final String industryName)
{
    final PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query q = null;
    q = pm.newQuery(Industry.class);
    q.setFilter("industryName == industryNameParam");
    q.declareParameters(String.class.getName() + " industryNameParam");
    final List<Industry> industry = (List<Industry>) q.execute(industryName.getBytes());
    boolean exists = !industry.isEmpty();
    if (q != null)
    {
        q.closeAll();
    }
    pm.close();
    return exists;
}
```

**JDO Entity**

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Industry implements StoreCallback
{
    @NotNull(message = "Industry Name is required.")
    private String          industryName;
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @PrimaryKey
    private Key             key;

    public Industry()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Key getIndustryKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public String getIndustryName()
    {
        return industryName;
    }

    @Override
    public void jdoPreStore()
    {
        if (industryName != null)
        {
            industryName = industryName.trim();
        }
    }
    public void setIndustryName(final String industryName)
    {
        this.industryName = industryName;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on a resolution or pinpointing an oversight would be very much appreciated.
Cheerio.

Comment: Your query is a bit strange. Can you post your JDO class and mapping?

Comment: I've added the JDO file in question. I did remove some of the getters/setters and properties for brevity. I'm open to suggestions on how to rewrite the query.

Comment: I'm still confused on your comma separated string. Is that input of the industryName param? Or the value of Industry.industryName? If the former are you passing the comma-separate string as input to a single method call? Can you also post the call to industryNameExists? It would help.

Comment: The comma separated string is set on the industryName of the Industry entity. I've added the persist operation and the call, to the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're calling  industryNameExists("Architecture, Engineering, and Drafting") and trying to match a JDO with industryName exactly equal "Architecture, Engineering, and Drafting"?

Assuming you don't have any typo or space difference the only thing suspect is the getBytes(). Try the following:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Industry.class, "this.industryName == :industryNameParam");
List<Industry> industry = (List<Industry>) q.execute(industryName);
```

You can also try variation filters like "this.industryName.equalsIgnoreCase(:industryNameParam)" and "this.industryName.startWith(:industryNameParam)" to troubleshoot.

If it still does not work, try logging the SQL generated for review and compare with a hand-written query that works.